# A fast thinning algorithm

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I'm looking for a fast thinning algorithm that can be readily implemented using OpenCV. The mention of the library is because there are certain things that can be done in a jiffy in say, Mathematica or MATLAB which would require lines of handcode in OpenCV+C.

The algorithm must satisfy the 1 pixel thickness and connectedness criteria.

Has anyone got any experience in implementing one of the tons of available algorithms out there? - Literally spoilt for choice at the sheer number of papers Google threw up. Any pointers in the right direction would do.

Comment: "has anyone got any experience" type questions tend not to be well answered: do you have a more specific question?

Comment: @Autopulated: that's true however i *am* asking something a bit vague - there are quite a few fast thinning algorithms, the question is has anyone implemented any using OpenCV and C/C++?

Comment: Hello @AruniRC, do you finally get some satisfactory implementation?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Please check some thinning implementations in my blog:

1. [Zhang-Suen algorithm](http://opencv-code.com/quick-tips/implementation-of-thinning-algorithm-in-opencv/). ([copy on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20160322113207/http://opencv-code.com/quick-tips/implementation-of-thinning-algorithm-in-opencv/))
2. [Guo-Hall algorithm](http://opencv-code.com/quick-tips/implementation-of-guo-hall-thinning-algorithm/). ([copy on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20160314104646/http://opencv-code.com/quick-tips/implementation-of-guo-hall-thinning-algorithm/))

Both using OpenCV 2.x API.

Comment: finally. i ended up using Zhang-Suen, but nice answer.

Comment: You should know that your implementation in the post is buggy. It will address outside of the image along the far edges.

Comment: @flowfree why your blog is down. it was a good reference page.

Answer (score 11):

for the sake of completeness, I'm posting here a set of thinning algorithms implemented using OpenCV and C/C++ that I found out on the net while answering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10866173/297353) question. These have adequately answered this question for my needs. Putting them here in case others have similar requirements.

1. [OpenCV code for thinning](http://opencv-users.1802565.n2.nabble.com/Morphological-thinning-operation-from-Z-Guo-and-R-W-Hall-quot-Parallel-Thinn-td4225544.html) (Guo and Hall algo, works with CvMat inputs)
2. [The JR Parker implementation](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.opencv/36588) using OpenCV
3. Possibly more efficient code [here](http://www.eml.ele.cst.nihon-u.ac.jp/~momma/wiki/wiki.cgi/OpenCV/%E7%B4%B0%E7%B7%9A%E5%8C%96.html) (uses OpenCV optimized access methods a lot, however most of the page is in Japanese!)

Comment: Acctually, the 3rd one runs really slower than the two of @flowfree 's answer

Answer (score 5):

I used Zhang-Suen as well Guo-Hall; both produced satisfactory results but not the best ones. Then I tried "A Modified Parallel Thinning Algorithm" by Y. Y. ZHANG and P.S.P Wang. It was far better than the previous two algorithms. Anyone looking for a good thinning algorithm should try it since it is faster and more effective than the other two.

Comment: did you find any implementation or article explaining this modification? Can you elaborate around how much faster it is?

Comment: If you download the research papers and read through them, you will notice that the Zhang-Wang method does only one iteration and additionally, it has some different conditions to be checked. I processed binary images of size 1600 * 1200. It took approx. 5 sec for Zhang-Suen and approx. 3 sec for Zhang-Wang method.

Comment: Hi Vikramjit, can you share the implementation or describe how you combined the last two conditions? I read the paper but wasn’t sure how to combine the conditions p11=1, p6=0, with conditions p8=0, p15=1 for the modified thinning algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help you, but I've used this library and found it very useful, (which includes thinning/skeletonisation). You can download the source here:

http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/

and a good article of its use here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/Image_Processing_Lab.aspx