# openCV shape recognition basic shape

Tags: image, opencv, shapes, image-recognition

So, I have image simple like this:

[image]

After doing findContours by openCV, I get a vector of curves, which after drawing look like this:

[image]

but I want vector of curves which look just like single line and not around figure, like this:

[image]

is there an openCV function for that, or should I use another algorithm? what do you suggest?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080383/a-fast-thinning-algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, a way to do what you want would be to use a [thinning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton) algorithm. You will find an implementation with OpenCV [here](http://opencv-code.com/quick-tips/implementation-of-thinning-algorithm-in-opencv/).

The steps are :

Take the reverse of your image, to get this :

[image]

Then apply the thinning algorithm :

[image]

Matlab code to do this :

```
I = imread('image.jpg');
I = ~I;
It = bwmorph(I(:,:,1),'thin',Inf);
```