# How to generate a list of coordinate pairs from a simple image of a line

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image, curve

The task here is to generate a 2D path for a robot which replicates a (hand) drawn line. The line is a simple shape being a curve or squiggle and always has one start and one end point. An example of a squiggle is pictured here.

[image: Squiggle: open curve, single pixel, no aliasing, black on gray background]

I used OpenCV's cv2.findContours which finds both sides of the line and so generates a list of coordinates that describe both sides. What I need is a single coordinate path that would (in effect) run down the center of the line, this being the path that the robot would follow.

scikit-image's skimage.measure.find_contours generated a similar result.

I tried with an image that has one edge such as:

[image: simple closed horseshoe like shape filled with white on a black background]

so that the algorithm finds only one edge. The resulting coordinate path is closer to what I need however results in a closed polygon and a coordinate path like this:

[image: matplotlib plot of curve points (rendered in blue) extracted from the closed curve above on a white background with a light gray grid]

The boundary (straight) edge of the image is included, which is not desired.

So I guess I have two options that I can see. One is an algorithm that finds the mid-point between two edges along a curve (rather than finding both edges). Option two is to ignore the boundary edge of the image simply by filtering out those coordinates in that region, but that seems clunky.

Comment: That looks like a promising start but I wonder if your problem can be simplified. What is the input ? Where do these images of curves come from ? (It sounds like would be much easier if you got the source coordinates that get rendered into those lines as opposed to getting the rasterised curves to then extract points again). Will the algorithm need ot handle both open and closed curves ? Would the order in which the curves are drawn matter or not ?

Comment: could be thinning a good way to go , once you have a single pixel line you use its coords as path ? Not sure about good packages supporting it , here some hints : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38489449/getting-lines-with-1-pixel-thickness-from-contour-image-using-dilate-erode-or Getting lines with 1 pixel thickness from contour image using dilate / erode or non-maximum-suppression

Comment: here https://answers.opencv.org/question/163561/looking-for-a-thinningskeletonizing-algorithm-with-opencv-in-python/  pip install opencv-contrib-python image = cv2.imread("opencv.png")
thinned = cv2.ximgproc.thinning(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY))

Comment: Thanks for the info. The images are generated in paint.net by fitting a spline or Bezier curve to a photo of a pattern which is baked into a pie crust. Currently, a number of employees have the full-time job of drawing 'faces' on pies to denote the flavor... the task we have is to replace this process with a robot cell. The customer has requested the ability to generate new 'faces' so the process to do that needs to be easily accomplished by someone who is not a controls systems engineer with some Python skills (that's me).

Comment: If you can drive a single pixel line you could get the coordinates from pillow or any other tool that load the images as an array starting from getting all the coords of black pixel and than using an alghorithm that finds a first pixel than order them adding the first closest one coord to the first and doing the same for all the rest (cant go back to the previous pixel though) until you dont have any pixel left. Does it sounds right ??? I just wake up so not sure my reasoning is right

Comment: CONTINUED FROM ABOVE  ... on a second thought how would I find the start or end of trajectory ? maybe one of the two points that has only one neighbour in the one pixel distance range ??

Comment: opencv needs a routine to trace thinned lines into graph structures... [last time someone asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77560561/python-cv2-draw-a-center-curve-in-a-curved-object), I gave it some more thought (and a bit of Python) but that OP seemed to have lost interest.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz can you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77560561/python-cv2-draw-a-center-curve-in-a-curved-object OP images , running his code I dont get same risults , if I dont blur the starting image a get a full coverage of the worm by countour but its not smooth and get a wicked line

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz can you have a look at stackoverflow.com/questions/77560561/… OP images , running his code I dont get same risults , if I dont blur the starting image a dont get a full coverage of the worm by countour but its not smooth and get a wicked line , using original code I miss a bit of the tails of the worm and line is not single at one end

Answer (score 3):

Here's a short bit of code that does the following

1. Find the two end points, which are pixels with one neighbor.
2. Get the contour. It will run *on* the edge pixels of the shape. Where it's not properly thinned, both halves of the contour will differ. You'll see in the picutres.
3. Split contour by which points are end points
4. ???
5. Profit

Since your picture is all black, except for the alpha channel, I'll just use that. I'll also chop off the empty space around it.

```py
im = cv.imread("ARuYh.png", cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
mask = im[:,:,3] > 0 # bool array. you'll see me using astype() a few times
# and something involving cv.boundingRect() and slicing
```

[image: mask, detailed view]

Notice how the contour isn't properly thinned (apparent 4-connectivity in places). That *can* be a problem if any of the ends end diagonally instead of axis-aligned. A different thinning mode may work better.

Now let's count neighbors with 8-connectivity, for every pixel, even the unset ones:

```py
neighbor_kernel = np.uint8([
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1]])

neighbors_count = cv.filter2D(mask.astype(np.uint8), cv.CV_8U, neighbor_kernel)
```

Get the single contour:

```py
contours, _ = cv.findContours(mask.astype(np.uint8), cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) # mask itself is a bool array
[contour] = contours # unpacking the single contour
```

Dissect it:

```py
# find endpoint indices
endpoint_indices = [
    i for i, [(x,y)] in enumerate(contour)
    if neighbors_count[y,x] == 1
]

# there must be exactly two
[i0, i1] = endpoint_indices

# slice the contour
half_contour = contour[i0:i1+1]
```

And a little visualization: `i0` is red, `i1` is blue, half-contour is green. You can tell which half of the full contour it is by where the line isn't thinned properly and it's hugging one side of the line.

[image: result]

That wasn't much code and I think the concept is clear as well. Any further questions?

Comment: Was wondering about 4-connectivity bit , I dont know anything about image processing, got an explanation here https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/46377/71178 , so there is 8 connectivity and 4 connectivity is there 2 connectivity too ? Any link to a simple dumb proif ( the dumb its me) explanation ?

Comment: tried your code with your TnQh1.png white curve over black background. The endpoint_indices result empty = [] , I think you can tell from the flat parallel to width ends  of the contour shown in your last image RcJXJ.png no point there could have a neighbors_count ==1 . Am I missing something ?

Comment: found something interesting here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60873271/opencv-how-to-get-middle-line-of-a-contour  : opencv-how-to-get-middle-line-of-a-contour  isnt Python , dont know MatLab , but for us the problem kepps being how to get the two ends of the line ... I think

Comment: obviously the pictures in my answer are illustrations, not data. I've resized them with nearest neighbor interpolation. you need to use the data in the *question* -- that answer you linked solves the problem in a roundabout way: from Connected Component (raster data) to contour back to CC, and then a distance transform and ridge finding, which is ***basicallly thinning***. so let's not do that but stick to thinning itself, as long as it's a mode that leaves properly thinned data. I figured it'd suffice to mention that, not have to re-thin the line.

Comment: Is there a way once you use thinning like in my first solution picture in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77974236/9877065 thinned_worm.png (thinned_worm.png: PNG image data, 2371 x 2371, 8-bit grayscale, non-interlaced calculated with thinned = cv2.ximgproc.thinning(drawing_gray, thinningType = cv2.ximgproc.THINNING_ZHANGSUEN)) to start from one of the ends and calculate the lenght of all possible single lines that arise from the one pixel thinned filled contour keeping just the longest line calculated ? Is not the real median of the worm pic but should be a good approximation, your though

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution to this particular problem which is to use cv2.findContours which as mentioned finds both sides of a line then generating the robot path by simply using only the first 50% of the points. This works as, conveniently, the algorithm must track along one side of the line then back along the other side. I only need one side and accuracy is not that important in this application.

Comment: "by simply using only the first 50% of the points." what does it mean ? how can you get only the right 50% , does it whork over a whirl shaped line ?

Comment: This is going to potentially give you half of the line traced twice, instead of the full line traced once. You need to find the right point to start.

Comment: a preparatory step would have to find where the contour has its "ends". on the contour itself, I don't *know* of a solution but these end points can be found in the raster image with neighbor counting. the contours should contains points equal to those.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comments:

> If you can drive a single pixel line you could get the coordinates from pillow or any other tool that load the images as an array starting from getting all the coords of black pixel and than using an algorithm that finds a first pixel than order them adding the first closest one coord to the first and doing the same for all the rest (can't go back to the previous pixel though) until you don't have any pixel left. Does it sound right?

Also:

> CONTINUED FROM ABOVE ... on a second thought how would I find the start or end of trajectory? Maybe one of the two points that has only one neighbor in the one pixel distance range?

Using your one pixel image file, I called it `curve.jpg` :

[image]

The file is:

`curve.png: PNG image data, 409 x 376, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced`

I tried my above mentioned approach up to the finding of the two tails (start and end point of the curve), code needs to be completed using same approach :

1. choose a starting point
2. loop over : find neighbor/neighbors, choose one and keep going of course removing pixel already picked-up in these steps, until hopefully the unchoosen tails
3. get the coords you stored while removing pixels from the starting pool of black ones you choose to loop on
4. Scale and translate path from picture coordinates system to the one used by robot

My code, so far:

```
import PIL as pil

from PIL import Image

import numpy as np

print(pil.__version__)


def neighbors(matrix: np.ndarray, x: int, y: int):
    """
    
    stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73811239/query-the-value-of-the-four-neighbors-of-an-element-in-a-numpy-2d-array
    
    """

    x_len, y_len = np.array(matrix.shape) - 1
    nbr = []
    if x > x_len or y > y_len:
        return nbr
    if x != 0:
        nbr.append(matrix[x-1][y])
        if y != 0:
            nbr.append(matrix[x-1][y-1])
        if y != y_len:
            nbr.append(matrix[x-1][y+1])
    if y != 0:
        nbr.append(matrix[x][y-1])
        if x != x_len:
            nbr.append(matrix[x+1][y-1])
    if x != x_len:
        nbr.append(matrix[x+1][y])
        if y != y_len:
            nbr.append(matrix[x+1][y+1])
    if y != y_len:
        nbr.append(matrix[x][y+1])
    return nbr




img_array = np.array(Image.open('curve.png'))

print('\n\n___________________________')

print(img_array)

print(img_array.shape , img_array.size , img_array.ndim)

# print(img_array)

print(np.where(img_array != 0))

max_ele = np.amax(img_array)  

min_ele = np.amin(img_array)

print(max_ele , min_ele)



# create a reverse imang 0 --> 1 , 1 -->0
img_array2 = 1 - img_array



print(img_array2.shape , img_array2.size , img_array2.ndim)

print(img_array2)

max_ele = np.amax(img_array2)  

min_ele = np.amin(img_array2)

print(max_ele , min_ele)



print(img_array2[0][0])




nei = neighbors(img_array2, 1, 1)

print(nei , len(nei))
    

tails = []

for i in np.ndenumerate(img_array2):
    
    # print(i ,type(i))
    
    if i[1] == 1:
    
        neib = neighbors(img_array2, i[0][0], i[0][1])
        
        # print(neib)
        
        if sum(neib) == 1:
            
            tails.append(i)
            
print('\n\n tails : ' , tails)



result = np.zeros((img_array2.shape[0], img_array2.shape[1], 4)).astype(np.uint8)

print(result.shape)


result[result == 0] = 255

for i in tails :
    
    result[i[0][0]][i[0][1]] = (0,0,0,255) 
    



print(np.where(result == (0,255,0,255)))

print(result[0][0])
print(result[192][173])
print(result[219][279])

# print(result)


image2 = Image.fromarray(result.astype(np.uint8) , 'RGBA')


image2.save('test.png')
```

my output file , to prove `tails` could be right ones : `test.png` ;

`test.png: PNG image data, 409 x 376, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced`

[image]

tails , highlighted :

[image]

merged with , input 'curve.png' file :

[image]

I am sure there are faster/better ways to accomplish this, my Numpy and Pillow are very basic level, but I believe could be double with a single pixel, continuous line as your example.

If your actual line is different, please post it, together with your OpenCV code, I am always interested in examples that show solutions to real life problems.

**NOTE ON Pixel Neighbors:**

They can be more than 2:

[image]

Kept going on, till the end, code in kind of messy, but I wanted to try to get the wanted result, I am reposting entire code:

```
import PIL as pil

from PIL import Image

import math

import numpy as np

print(pil.__version__)


def neighbors(matrix: np.ndarray, x: int, y: int):
    """
    
    stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73811239/query-the-value-of-the-four-neighbors-of-an-element-in-a-numpy-2d-array
    
    """

    x_len, y_len = np.array(matrix.shape) - 1
    nbr = []
    if x > x_len or y > y_len:
        return nbr
    if x != 0:
        nbr.append(matrix[x-1][y])
        if y != 0:
            nbr.append(matrix[x-1][y-1])
        if y != y_len:
            nbr.append(matrix[x-1][y+1])
    if y != 0:
        nbr.append(matrix[x][y-1])
        if x != x_len:
            nbr.append(matrix[x+1][y-1])
    if x != x_len:
        nbr.append(matrix[x+1][y])
        if y != y_len:
            nbr.append(matrix[x+1][y+1])
    if y != y_len:
        nbr.append(matrix[x][y+1])
    return nbr




img_array = np.array(Image.open('curve.png'))

print('\n\n___________________________')

print(img_array)

print(img_array.shape , img_array.size , img_array.ndim)

# print(img_array)

print(np.where(img_array != 0))

max_ele = np.amax(img_array)  

min_ele = np.amin(img_array)

print(max_ele , min_ele)



# create a reverse imang 0 --> 1 , 1 -->0
img_array2 = 1 - img_array



print(img_array2.shape , img_array2.size , img_array2.ndim)

print(img_array2)

max_ele = np.amax(img_array2)  

min_ele = np.amin(img_array2)

print(max_ele , min_ele)



print(img_array2[0][0])




nei = neighbors(img_array2, 1, 1)

print(nei , len(nei))
    

tails = []

points = []

for i in np.ndenumerate(img_array2):
    
    # print(i ,type(i))
    
    if i[1] == 1:
    
        neib = neighbors(img_array2, i[0][0], i[0][1])
        
        # print(neib)
        
        if sum(neib) == 1:
            
            tails.append(i)
            
        else :
            
            points.append(i[0])
            
print('\n\n tails : ' , tails)



result = np.zeros((img_array2.shape[0], img_array2.shape[1], 4)).astype(np.uint8)

print(result.shape)


result[result == 0] = 255

for i in tails :
    
    result[i[0][0]][i[0][1]] = (0,0,0,255) 
    

# print(result)

image2 = Image.fromarray(result.astype(np.uint8) , 'RGBA')

image2.save('test.png')


def neighbors_coords(matrix: np.ndarray, x: int, y: int):
    """
    
    stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73811239/query-the-value-of-the-four-neighbors-of-an-element-in-a-numpy-2d-array
    
    """

    x_len, y_len = np.array(matrix.shape) - 1
    nbr = []
    if x > x_len or y > y_len:
        return nbr
    if x != 0 : 
        if matrix[x-1][y] == 1:
            nbr.append((x-1,y))
        if y != 0:
            if matrix[x-1][y-1] == 1 :
                nbr.append((x-1,y-1))
        if y != y_len:
            if matrix[x-1][y+1] == 1:
                nbr.append((x-1,y+1))
    if y != 0:
        if matrix[x][y-1] == 1:
            nbr.append((x, y-1))
        if x != x_len:
            if matrix[x+1][y-1] == 1 :
                nbr.append((x+1 , y-1))
    if x != x_len:
        if matrix[x+1][y] == 1 :
            nbr.append((x+1 , y))
        if y != y_len:
            if matrix[x+1][y+1] == 1 :
                nbr.append((x+1 ,y+1))
    if y != y_len:
        if matrix[x][y+1] == 1:
            nbr.append((x, y+1))
            
    # print('nbr : ', nbr , x_len, y_len)
    
    nbr_dist = []
    
    for i in nbr :
        
        dist = math.dist([x,y], [i[0],i[1]])
        
        nbr_dist.append((i[0],i[1], dist))
        

    nbr_dist.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[2] , reverse = False)  # sort points to get closest one first
    
    print('nbr_dist : ', nbr_dist , x , y)
    
    return nbr_dist



print(tails)

# print(points, len(points), type(points))

print('points : ', len(points), type(points))


start = tails[0]

img_array2[tails[0][0][0]][tails[0][0][1]] = 0
# img_array2[tails[1][0][0]][tails[1][0][1]] = 0


print('\nstart , : ', start)


cnt = 0

coords = []

first = start[0]

print('first : ', first , first[0] , first[1])

coords.append(start[0])


while points != [] :
    
    print('first : ' , first)
    
    second_next = neighbors_coords(img_array2, first[0] , first[1])
    
    print('list : ', second_next)
    
    second_next = second_next[0]
    
    img_array2[second_next[0]][second_next[1]] = 0
    
    print('second_next : ', second_next)
    
    first = second_next
    
    print('first : ', first)
    
    print(len(points))
    
    points.remove((first[0],first[1]))
    
    coords.append(second_next[:2])
    
    cnt +=1
    
    print('cnt : ', cnt  )
    
# print('tails : ', tails[1][0])
coords.append(tails[1][0])

print('\n\nCoordinates : ' , coords , len(coords))
    
print('\n\n tails : ' , tails)
    
points_img = np.zeros((img_array2.shape[0], img_array2.shape[1], 4)).astype(np.uint8)

for i in coords :
    
    print(i)
    
    points_img[i[0]][i[1]] = (255,0,0,255) 
    

image3 = Image.fromarray(points_img.astype(np.uint8) , 'RGBA')

image3.save('check.png')

# image3.show()


from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = [-i[0] for i in coords]

y = [i[1] for i in coords]

s = [ n*n/200 for n in range(len(x))]

plt.scatter(y,x, s = s)

plt.show()
```

Output :

`test.png: PNG image data, 409 x 376, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced` as above ;

`check.png: PNG image data, 409 x 376, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced` , redrawn image to checkm my coordinates are complete

[image]

And `matplotlib` plot that draws coordinates from first to last increasing dot size at each coordinate, to show direction of 2D x,y path:

[image]

And here is evidence that my approach has not taken into account your starting image Pixel aspect ratio (PAC)! Ouch! or is it the print size that matters?  ..... just a `matplotlib` issue?

Fixed using `plt.axis('equal')`:

[image]